# Extract area inside vector of points

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to extract the area enclosed by a vector of points which do not necessarily form a rectangle. For example:

[image: area to extract]

I want to extract the area inside the yellow figure.
The way I drew the yellow figure is by drawing lines between pairs of points that I have as a `vector<Point2f>`.

I tried `floodFill`ing with some color starting from some pixel inside, in order to use this as a mask later and I got this:

[image: floodfill inside]
*(problem here is obviously the black holes inside the letters)*

I also tried filling the *outside* area with the same color as the text (white):

[image: fill outside]
But some black wholes remained outside...

How can I do this correctly without leaving any holes?

Comment: Answer for a deleted comment (*do the dots represent the contours of the text*) - Not exactly... They represent the contours of some of it... For each vertical group of contours in the original image, I saved the median one. For example for the letter **é** (**e** with accent) I might have only the contour of **e** (without the accent)

Comment: The purpose was to extract the middle line... So I sorted the contours by their `x` coordinate and then grouped `y`-close contours and from each group I took the middle one. I might have to find another way to fill the exact needed contours and then it'll be easy to extract them. But for now this is all I got

Comment: How were you able to extract the central line of the text? I am curious!

Comment: @JeruLuke - I found the contours of the text by `cv::findcontours()`, then I sorted the contours by their `x` coordinate (so vertically aligned contours become adjacent), then took groups that are close by their `y` coordinates (this groups up 3 letters in a vertical line [at least 3 contours]). Then from every group I looked at the centers of the contours (using moments), and took the median. Finally I took the boundaries of the median contour of each group. I added a small margin around the boundaries and pulled lines between all outer boundaries. It's not perfect though

Comment: @JeruLuke - I tried another way: I found contours [see here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AAnaCWPLCgtcmsR3eI65-PK59DI5NL7m), then I iterated over the image horizontally and for every vertical line I found the upper and lower bounds (0 becoming not 0) to define the text area. Then I took the contour which its center is in the middle of that area. All the way to the end of the image [see result here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14TD-u0WK3V8cmjSeuymSRQC-RdUnCqe9). However, if I fill the letters in this result, it doesn't look very good

Comment: Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fill the polygon defined by your vector of points, you can use [`fillPoly`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/drawing_functions.html#fillpoly). Draw the polygon on an empty image and use that as a mask in a second step.

Comment: Makes sense... Thanks I'll try it